# SQL Server log shipping for DC and DR on cloud

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

If I would like to do log shipping to cloud DC DR.
But the DR server at normal times will be turned off.
It will turn on only if the DC has failed.
So is it possible way to do it? when the DC failed the DR server can be used instead of the DC and continue the log shipping?

Thank you

Comment: The logic doesn't make sense. You want to send data to a server that is powered off?

Answer (score 1):

Log shipping implies that something on the other end is processing those logs. Since you don't have anything that would be doing that: "DR server at normal times will be turned off", - log shipping is the wrong approach.

Perhaps you want to consider storage and/or VM snapshots.